# Pass nid as argument to embedded view

Tags: views, theming

I am using twig tweak to embed a view in node.tpl.twig

{{ drupal_view('testview', 'block_1', '12') }}

how can I pass current nid {{ node.id() }} as argument instead of static '12' in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Oh - it is quite simple :)

```
{{ drupal_view('testview', 'block_1', node.id() ) }}
```

- sorry still learning basics :D