# trying to insert a view inside a view using twig tweak module

Tags: views, theming

I am trying to insert a view inside a view but struggling a bit

I have a view called My Class with all my fields in it, this works fine.

I have a view with a contextual filter called 
Students Block, (This is using the reference to the my class content type that populates the My Class view) 
machine name       students_block
and a BlockView called  students_block

I've set up a contextual filter and reference to My Class and again this works as expected when used as a block.

Now I am trying to add the students_block in the middle of the My Class view.

I have set up content hidden ID to expose the NID, and then a global custom text field that has as follows

{{ drupal_view('Students Block', 'students_block', nid) }}

I can't whatever I do get any results, if I remove the nid I do get my original view, and I have tried other blocks as per the examples and that seems to work for me

Can anyone assist please

Thanks

Comment: Try unhiding the id.

Comment: You do have https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak installed? See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235812/pass-nid-as-argument-to-embedded-view you may need to do `node.id()` instead of `nid`. Also check https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak/issues/2993700